# Topology problem: Proving that sections are open

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I have been trying to learn some basics of topology on my own, I have learnt the basic definitions. I have not been able to understand the proof provided in the text. Could anyone provide a clearer proof, or kindly explain me the outline of the proof provided here?

Comment: What part of it are you stuck on?

Comment: The first 2 lines of the proof have little content. I don't understand the 3rd line.

Comment: Looks like it's just unraveling the definition. The topology on $X$ is given by the basis $\prod A_i$ with $A_i\subset \Gamma_i$ open and all but finitely many $A_i$ equal to $\Gamma_i$ itself. With that definition of $G$, the "all but finitely many" bit carries over to $\prod E_i$. That's probably not particularly clear either, but there's really nothing in that proof beyond unraveling the definition of the product topology.

Comment: @anomaly, thanks for your reply. I think the part I was wondering about is the following. In a topology, how can we be certain that a point in an open set X would be contained in another open set Y, such that $X\subset Y$?
I understand how this would hold for the case for a metric space by definition.
Also, it seems that the proof holds for possibly uncountable index set $I$, am I right?

Comment: $Y = X$ works, or take the entire space. Sure, the proof works for arbitrary $I$.

Comment: I interpreted the subset sign as a strict subset, hence, $Y=X$ would be ruled out. Could you kindly explain what you mean by taking the entire space as $X$ but still having $X\subset Y$?

Comment: Take $Y$, not $X$, to be the entire space. I don't know what custom your particular book uses, but it's not unusual for $\subset$ to be used as $\subseteq$. (It's also not unusual for it to mean strict subsets, but I think the former is more common.)